# CDF function from list

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, distributions

How can I get the CDF for a list of values ​​containing the value of a random variable and its probability?

I have:

```
grs[n_] := If[n == 14, 0.9^(n - 1)*0.1 + 0.9^14, 0.9^(n - 1)*0.1]

tableOfRandomVariable = Table[{n, grs[n]}, {n, 1, 14}]

hDist = HistogramDistribution[tableOfRandomVariable];

DiscretePlot[CDF[hDist, x], {x, 0, 14}, ExtentSize -> Right, ExtentMarkers -> {"Filled", "Empty"}]
```

It is not works.

When i try to do:

```
grs[n_] := If[n == 14, 0.9^(n - 1)*0.1 + 0.9^14, 0.9^(n - 1)*0.1]

tableOfRandomVariable = Table[grs[n], {n, 1, 14}] (*This list not contain random values, only probability list*)

hDist = HistogramDistribution[tableOfRandomVariable];

DiscretePlot[CDF[hDist, x], {x, 0, 14}, ExtentSize -> Right, ExtentMarkers -> {"Filled", "Empty"}]
```

I expect about:

[image: Expected output]

But mathematica gives:

[image: Wrong output]

How I can get CDF plot for first table of variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[
  tableOfRandomVariable[[All, 2]] -> tableOfRandomVariable[[All, 1]]];

DiscretePlot[CDF[dist, x], {x, 0, 14}, ExtentSize -> Right, 
 ExtentMarkers -> {"Filled", "Empty"}]
```

[image]